# Is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }nz^{n!n}=0$ for $|z|<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }nz^{n!n}=0$ for $|z|<1$? We have a $\infty \cdot 0$ case, then how we proceed? How to use the L'Hospital's Rule?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need L'Hospital, considering $$\frac{(n+1)z^{(n+1)!(n+1)}}{nz^{n!n}}$$ for example yields the result, or taking $n$-th roots, or $n!n$-th roots.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to prove it for $0<z<1$. Define $a_n:=n z^{n! n}$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}nz^{(n+1)!(n+1)-n!n}$. Since $(n+1)!(n+1)-n!n\geqslant (n+1)n!n-n!n=n!n²$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}nz^{n^2\cdot n!}\leqslant 2z^{n^2\cdot n!}\lt 1/2$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: But what all this means? I need to find why the limit is 0.

Comment: @Ian Simply use the definition of [limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_Definition)

Answer (score 0):

Without any complex math, consider what happens to the module of this number: $n|z|^{n!n}<<<n|z|^n\rightarrow 0$ if $|z|<1$.

Comment: But why $n|z|^n\rightarrow 0$? We have a $\infty \cdot 0$ case so should use L'Hospital.

Comment: Is $\infty \cdot 0=0$?

Comment: No, $\infty\cdot 0\not= 0$. But $n|z|^n\rightarrow 0$ is in reals, not complex numbers, and is one of the well-known facts. So, my answer is basically how you can get what you need from a convergence in reals.